# Show function is not differentiable between a manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to solve the following problem

> Let $E$ the image of function $\varphi:(0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with
> $\varphi(t) = (\sin t, \sin 2t)$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ the differential
> structure in $E$ give by the chart $x:=\varphi^{-1}$. Show that $F:E\to E$ defined by $F(x,y)=(x,-y)$ is not differentiable.

Reading the book Analysis and Algebra on Differentiable Manifolds: A Workbook for Students, of Masqué, I see the problem below:

[image]

So, define $E=\{(\sin(t),\sin(2t)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : t \in (0,2\varepsilon)\}$.
Like problem above we have that $x:\mathbb{R}^2 \to (0,2\pi)$ where $x(\sin(t),\sin(2t))=t$.

One way to show that a application between a manifold is not differentiable, is show that the composition $x \circ F \circ x^{-1}$ is not differentiable.

My question is, how can I show that is not differentiable?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: 1. It looks as if $x = \varphi^{-1}$ denotes both a chart and a Cartesian coordinate. Those are not the same $x$. 2. The mapping $F$ isn't even continuous in the chart $x$, as the hint/solution says: The induced bijection on $(0, 2\pi)$ has a jump discontinuity at $\pi$.